# As new to php i am not clear over the jumps betveen php-pages. My code below. is this the right way?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, stored-procedures

1. I want to se available dates in a dropdown - done
2. After i´v choosen the date i want to see the available time - done
3. The customer should be able to book the choosen timeslot - I think i knowe this one, work in progress.

**Problem**: I want the customer to se the dropdown and the result in the same page and maybe change it when the time comes visably. I´v been playing around with `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"` but thats not it i belive.

I am a bit lost in best practice regarding files and jumps betveen them. I have separated the php and html code in different pages. When i´m ready i lift the php-files to includes folder offcourse.

HTML - form with dropdown and submit
php - fill dropdown with dates
html - form with result text fields
php - code for result (timeslot data)

**form_date.php**

```
<?PHP
  require_once('booking_available_dates.php');
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<form name='date_registration' action='booking_available_dates.php' method='POST'>
   
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="select" class="col-2 col-form-label">Hämta första lediga tid för valt datum</label> 
    <div class="col-10">
      <select id="date_input" name="date_input" class="custom-select">
      <?php foreach ($dates as $row): ?>
      <option><?=$row["date_booking_customer"]?></option>
      <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-4 col-8">
      <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Hämta tid!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**booking_available_dates.php**

```
<?php
require_once('dbhandler.php');
$dbh = new DBHandler();

if ($dbh->getInstance() === null) {
    die("No database connection");
}

try {
    $sql = "CALL `booking_dates_available`();";
    $stmt = $dbh->getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $dates=$stmt->fetchAll();
} 

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

**booking_confirm_view.php** (not ready - work in progress)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="date" class="col-4 col-form-label">Datum</label> 
    <div class="col-8">
      <input id="date" readonly="readonly" name="date" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="time" class="col-4 col-form-label">Tid</label> 
    <div class="col-8">
      <input id="time" readonly="readonly" name="time" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="owner" class="col-4 col-form-label">Båtägare</label> 
    <div class="col-8">
      <input id="owner" name="owner" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-4">Medlem i HSS?</label> 
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input name="member" id="member_0" type="radio" required="required" class="custom-control-input" value="thru"> 
        <label for="member_0" class="custom-control-label">Medlem</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input name="member" id="member_1" type="radio" required="required" class="custom-control-input" value="false"> 
        <label for="member_1" class="custom-control-label">Ej medlem</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="boatname" class="col-4 col-form-label">Båtnamn</label> 
    <div class="col-8">
      <input id="boatname" name="boatname" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email" class="col-4 col-form-label">E-post</label> 
    <div class="col-8">
      <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="mobile" class="col-4 col-form-label">Mobilnummer</label> 
    <div class="col-8">
      <input id="mobile" name="mobile" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-4 col-8">
      <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**booking_available_time.php**

```
<?php
require_once('dbhandler.php');
$dbh = new DBHandler();

if ($dbh->getInstance() === null) {
    die("No database connection");
}

try {
    $sql = "CALL `booking_date_input` (:date_input);";
    $stmt = $dbh->getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date_input', $date_input, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $date_input = $_POST["date_input"];
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->fetchAll();
} 

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

`$result` is the array with the timeslot data.

Comment: @Svanta Stenberg
Use ajax call to fetch the result of dates and time then finally post the form.

Comment: If you specify no action, then the submit should bring you back to the same page, but with the sent data in the [superglobals `$_REQUEST` or better `$_GET` or `$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) (if submitted with method="post"). You can check if the expected property is set and what value was submitted (be sure to validate/sanitize the input to prevent security issues).

Comment: Thank you  @dbrumann.

"If you specify no action..." - one more breadcrum to my way to be a deasent programmer. :-) This pointer got me in the right direction.